# If this theorem holds for a semicircle, does it also hold for any sector of a circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The theorem below holds for a semicircle (exactly half of a circle, AB is diameter). But does the same hold for any sector of a circle?

[image]

Comment: Try in some aplet, say Geogebra, Anyway I would say no.

Comment: What happens if you consider a $359^\circ$ arc? Then $AB$ is very small, but everythinf else can be about as long as the radius ...

Comment: cannot get your formula to work in Geogebra, are you sure about ? when $C \to D$ then $CE, DE \to 0$!

Comment: @caasdads your claim for semicircle is not true. Counterexample: take a circle with diameter 1. Then $AB^2=1,$ but $DE$ and $DB$ are clearly shorter than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Say you move $J$ to $I$, then $J=I$ and $L=I$. Now we would have:
$$ KI^2 +0 = HI^2$$ which does not hold (unles $K=H$).